# What's the difference between a facebook post.id and status.id?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the graph-api to walk information about a facebook user.  In looking at the connections for the User node, both 'posts' and 'statuses' are available.

When walking through the posts, I come across posts of the type 'status' that have slightly different information, than the equivalent status message.

In the example below, you can see that they are the same message, but the "Post Version" has an id of "100002912416196_212493188857760" while the "Status Version" has an id of "212493188857760".  Is one "more correct" than the other?  Is Facebook in the process of moving from using statuses (and links, etc) to just using posts (or vice versa)?  Any help someone could give would be appreciated.

Here's an example (edited to save space)

when called with https://graph.facebook.com/me/posts

```
"data": [
{
  "id": "100002912416196_212493188857760", 
  "from": {
    "name": "Ben Backup", 
    "id": "100002912416196" }, 
  "to": {
    "data": [{
        "name": "Dave Upify", 
        "id": "100001917301370"
      }] }, 
  "message": "With Dave Upify", 
...
  "type": "status", 
  "created_time": "2012-03-20T20:18:54+0000", 
  "updated_time": "2012-03-20T20:18:54+0000", 
  "comments": {
    "count": 0
  }, 
  "is_published": true
}
```

when called with https://graph.facebook.com/me/statuses

```
"data": [{
  "id": "212493188857760", 
  "from": {
    "name": "Ben Backup", 
    "id": "100002912416196" }, 
  "message": "With Dave Upify", 
  "place": {
    "id": "126533127390327", 
    "name": "Massachusetts Institute of Technology", 
    "location": {
      "street": "77 Massachusetts Avenue", 
      "city": "Cambridge", 
      "state": "MA", 
      "country": "United States", 
      "zip": "02139", 
      "latitude": 42.359430693405, 
      "longitude": -71.092129185382
    }
  }, 
  "updated_time": "2012-03-20T20:18:52+0000"
},
```

Comment: Good question.  I'd +1'd it.  Hopefully a Facebook engineer or developer will answer the question (however seeing them on stackoverflow is highly rare)